# Echo text during foreach unless final result

Tags: php

I currently have my code to output data from a database but I am unsure of how to append text during a foreach where the result is not the final entry.

```
//Print each result 
foreach($new_array as $array){

//print out a result with formatting  
Echo $Content1 = <<<CONTENT1
{"
CONTENT1;

Echo $array['f1'];

Echo $Content2 = <<<CONTENT2
"}{"
CONTENT2;

Echo $array['f2']; 

Echo ".";

Echo $array['f3'];

Echo $Content3 = <<<CONTENT3
"}
CONTENT3;
```

**Echo ", " //If not final entry**

```
};

?>
```

So in short transforming the output from;

{"Entry"}{"Name.ID"}{"Entry"}{"Name.ID"}

to;

{"Entry"}{"Name.ID"}, {"Entry"}{"Name.ID"}

Comment: well you can see from the code highlighting on the site that you have some serious errors.  Fix your logic errors start echoing out properly lower case echo not Echo also no need for using your phpdoc stuff.

Comment: PHPED likes to tell me echo is a misspelling of Echo, not that it makes a difference to the way it's interpreted... Also this is a hugely reduced version of my file I use heredoc instead of escaping characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$endvar=end($new_array);
```

it will store the last value in the array and then you can check it using **if condition**

```
foreach($new_array as $array){
if($array==$endvar)
{
// do whatever you want to do here
}
else
{
// else code
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For small data sets and if you have all the data available at once, you can use `implode`:

```
$content = array();
foreach ($new_array as $arr) {
    $content[] = <<<CONTENT
        {{$arr['f1']}}{{$arr['f2']}.{$arr['f3']}}
CONTENT;
}
print implode(',', $content);
```

You can also use an [array mapping function](https://www.php.net/array_map):

```
print implode(',', array_map(function($arr){
    return '{' . $arr['f1'] . '}{' . $arr['f2'].'.'.$arr['f3'].'}';
}, $new_array);
```

or

```
print implode(',', array_map(function($arr){
    return <<<ITEM
{$arr[f1]}{$arr[f2].$arr[f3]}
ITEM;
}, $new_array);
```

Otherwise, if you are loading data in a loop, save the field separator:

```
$before = '';
$content = '';
foreach ($new_array as $arr) {
    $content .= $before;
    $content .= "{{$arr[f1]}}{{$arr[f2]}.{$arr[f3]}}"
    $before = ',';
}
print $content;
```

or printing it a little at a time:

```
$before = '';
foreach ($new_array as $arr) {
    print $before;
    print "{{$arr[f1]}}{{$arr[f2]}.{$arr[f3]}}"
    $before = ',';
}
```

As a suggestion, do not use variables called `$array` (or `$string`, and so on); and in case this has to do with JSON encoding, check out also `json_encode`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$str = '';
foreach($new_array as $array){
   $str .= "{$array['f1']} {$array['f2']} {$array['f3']},";
}
echo substr($str,0,-1); `// trim last character of your string`
```